# Private field of enum class cannot be accessed by Nested enum

Tags: java, enums

When a nested enum class tries to access the outer, it gets an error message about being unable to access a non-static field in a static context. However making the field package local, or using the super keyword "fixes" the problem, which is not obvious from the error message.

If the enum were a nested class, it would have no trio

```
public enum EnumExample {
One {
    public int getMemberVariableFailes() {
        // error: non-static variable memberVariable cannot be referenced from a static context
        return memberVariable;
    }

    public int getMemberVariableOK() {
        return super.memberVariable;
    }

    public int getMemberVariable2OK() {
        return memberVariable2;
    }
};

private final int memberVariable = 1;
final int memberVariable2 = 1;
}
```

EXPECTED -

The error message doesn't make it clear that using the super. keyword would "fix" the problem. It doesn't appear to be correct behaviour, but if it is the error message gives no indication as to the solution.

ACTUAL -
The same behaviour as the following.

```
However following compiles absolutely fine.

public class Enumtest {
public class NestedNotEnum extends Enumtest {
    public int getMemberVariableFailes() {
        // compiles just fine.
        return memberVariable;
    }

    public int getMemberVariableOK() {
        return super.memberVariable;
    }
}
private final int memberVariable = 1;
}
```

Can some one elaborates why this is happening.

Comment: The One instance if both a subclass of EnumExample, and a static nested class of EnumExample. The field is defined in the superclass, and should be accessible to subclasses. It should thus be protected instead of private.

Comment: @JBNizet, you are right, but IMHO the text of error message is a little bit confusing. `One` indeed static member and a subclass of `EnumExample`. As a subclass it should not be able to access private member of super. But it can if `super` word is explicitly written. IMHO this is strange...

Comment: Yes this is my concern too... text message is quite confusing i ran it on both linux and solaris and both java 6 and java 7 but got same answer... :(

Comment: It's confusing, but not incorrect. Since the field is private, it's not accessible by subclasses. So the compiler assumes you want to access an outer instance field from a static nested class, hence the error. It could perhaps be better, and you could submit an RFE to Oracle, but now you should at least know why it happens, and how to fix the code.

Comment: @AlexR Its indeed a subclass, but an inner class as well which has access to the private fields of the enclosing type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is difference between the declared `enum` and the provided inner class example. You should consider the enums as '**static nested classes**' and *not* 'inner classes'. Now, the provided class example translates to:

```
public class Enumtest
{
    static class NestedNotEnum extends Enumtest {
        public int getMemberVariableFailes() {
            // error: non-static variable memberVariable cannot be referenced from a static context
            return memberVariable;
        }

        public int getMemberVariableOK() {
            return super.memberVariable;
        }
    }
    private final int memberVariable = 1;
}
```

Aren't these results similar to your expectations? Same as `EnumExample`, use the keyword super to fix the problem. However, this is still strange:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field memberVariable

as we still able to refer to memberVariable by using `super`!